# Mootools - Assign a function to all input text elements to empty/undo the content

Tags: mootools

Suppose i've many input type="text" all over a page.

I would like to erase the content of an input whenever i click into it. If i'll change the content, it will save it. If not, it will restore the original value.

I would like to assign this kind of function automatically (on document ready) to all of the input within the page.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Have you tried anything, if YES please post your code here.

Comment: Hey, the idea behind this site is to help people to solve punctual problems. You are just saying what you want to do like a client does with a web designer. So, try to tackle the problem first, and if doesn't work after trying, come to this site. By the way you just need to delete the value property, nothing fancy.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution, uses event delegation where parent element (document.body) monitors childrens (all inputs of type text) for events:

- focus ( it is triggered when the user focuses on an element )
- blur ( event occurs when an element loses focus )

---

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {

    document.body.addEvents({
        'focus:relay(input[type=text])': function(event, target) {
            this.original = this.get( 'value' );
            this.set( 'value', '' );
        },
        'blur:relay(input[type=text])': function(event, target) {
            if ( !this.get( 'value' ) ) this.set( 'value', this.original );
        }
    });

});
```